# Entities in src/test/java are not recognized

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, entity

As part of my tests I am creating a DAO that its sole purpose is in the tests. When attempting to run the unit test I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
```

It seems that when the entities reside in the src/test/java folder they don't get picked up. When moving the entity to src/main/java everything is working fine. Problem is that this DAO is solely for tests and I really don't want to put it in main. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Are u using annotations or xml config for entity ?

Comment: Annotations and jpa persistence.xml. The new DAO has all the proper annotations on it.

Comment: Is your entity inside `persistence.xml`? If not you need to add there

Comment: All the other entities are being automatically detected, why is this different?

Answer (score 0):

[If you are using JPA] You need to have a separate persistent unit(I would advice to have a separate persistence.xml in the test resources) for the test classes and need to mention all the actual ORM entities in the persistence.xml in `class` tag.

For instance, the strategy I followed, I created a TestUtility and in that I am injecting the persistent unit using CDI injection

`private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "persistence-unit-test";`

and building my entityManager:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        final EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't have `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` since it collides with the one in `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

Comment: It won't if you choose to have different `persistence-unit` name than the actual one in `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

Comment: and it will get picked automatically during test? just let's say if I name it `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence-test.xml`

Comment: I am talking about the `persistent-unit` tag in the `persistence.xml`. You need to device the strategy to inject the test persistence unit at the time you run test cases.

Comment: Oh, in this case I have a different persistence units for tests and dev, to be able to direct them to different locations. All the annotations are being automatically picked up, why this is not?